# e2e: Maxlength is not considered when using input().enter()

Tags: angularjs

In e2e testing, I want to simulate user typing in a input field. My input field has a maxlength in it. I want the maxlength to be consider, but I have not succeed to find a solution to it. Here's what I've tried:

```
<input type="text" id="myField" maxlength="10" ng-model="myModel" />
<span>{{myModel}}</span>
```

1) input("myModel").enter("ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ"). Both the myField input and the myModel model are set to "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ". Expected result: "ABCDEFGHIJ"

2) element("#myField").val("ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ"). The myField input is set to "ABCDEFGHIJ". Which is perfect! But the myModel is null.

Do you guys have a solution for this? I don't want to use ngMaxlength since I want to prevent to use to typing more than 10 caracters.

Many thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You could extend angular-scenario dsl and use a function similar to this one to inject a value in ngModelController

```
function typeIn(element, str) {
    var maxlength = parseInt(element.attr('maxlength'), 10);
    var value = element.val() + str;

    if (maxlength !== NaN) {
        value = value.substr(0, maxlength);
    }

    element.val(value);
    element.controller('ngModel').$setViewValue(value);
    element.scope().$apply();
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/nxNm9/1/